# Delete the first header row in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to delete the first header row of the table which is 'Table 2.......'. 
[image: original table]

I tried the code below

```
d1t2.columns = d1t2.iloc[0]
d1t2 = data1t2.reindex(d1t2.index.drop(0)).reset_index(drop=True)
d1t2.columns.name = None 
d1t2
```

But the result is: the second row of the table, which the row of `index=0`
has been deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close:

```
d1t2.columns = d1t2.iloc[0]
d1t2.columns.name=None
d1t2.drop(0, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

However, if you read `d1t2` from a file, it would be better to skip the first row.